# Simple Chat program C++ in MPI

Tags: c++, mpi

My program includes one rank process of server and one rank process of client. The client transfer a number (array of type Double) to server.

Here is my code

```
//Server rank
if (rank == 0){
    double buf[MAX_DATA];
    MPI_Open_port(MPI_INFO_NULL, port_name);
    printf("server available at %s\n", port_name);

    while (1) {
        MPI_Comm_accept(port_name, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &client);
        again = 1;
        while (again) {
            MPI_Recv(buf, MAX_DATA, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, client, &status);

            switch (status.MPI_TAG) {
            case 0: 
                MPI_Comm_free(&client);
                MPI_Close_port(port_name);
                MPI_Finalize();
                return 0;
            case 1:
                MPI_Comm_disconnect(&client);
                again = 0;
                break;
            case 2: /* do something */
                printf("case 2\n");
                break;
            default:
                /* Unexpected message type */
                MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
// client rank
else
{
    MPI_Comm server;
    double buf[MAX_DATA];
    MPI_Comm_connect(port_name, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &server);
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        int tag = 2; /* Action to perform */
        MPI_Send(buf, MAX_DATA, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, tag, server);
    }
    MPI_Send(buf, 0, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 1, server);
    MPI_Comm_disconnect(&server);
}

MPI_Finalize();
```

But the code doesn't work, and it is stucked when I type the command
"mpiexec -n 2 MPI_HelloWorld.exe" (There are 2 processes created to run the program)

I modify the code from this source : "http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/mpi-standard/mpi-report-2.0/node106.htm"

Program's result: it gets stucks: the server doesnot receive the message
[image]

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: If your processes belong to the same communicator why do you try to connect them via a port? These things are required to connect independent applications. Take a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mpi/9416/process-creation-and-management/29185/establishing-connection-between-two-independent-applications#t=201704071413180428244).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things:

1) The server needs to tell the client about the port that it will be accepting the communications on. So, before starting to accept needs to send a message to the client and tell client this port_name.

So, a call like this is needed:

```
MPI_Send(port_name, MPI_MAX_PORT_NAME, MPI_CHAR, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

And the client needs to receive this message. So, the client first needs to do:

```
MPI_Recv(port_name, MPI_MAX_PORT_NAME, MPI_CHAR, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

2) As the client/server requires a point-to-point communication (you could have multiple clients but only between two processes at the same time), so we cannot use `MPI_Comm_World`(which includes all processes) in `MPI_Comm_accept()` and `MPI_Comm_connect()`. The correct communicator to use is `MPI_COMM_SELF`.

So those calls need to be changed to:

```
MPI_Comm_accept(port_name, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF, &client);
```

and

```
MPI_Comm_connect(port_name, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF, &server);
```

The following code has been tested on my system and runs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#define MAX_DATA    100

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

  int rank, size;
  char port_name[MPI_MAX_PORT_NAME];

  MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);  /* starts MPI */
  MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);    /* get current process id */
  MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);    /* get number of processes */

  //Server rank
  if (rank == 0){
    double buf[MAX_DATA];
    MPI_Open_port(MPI_INFO_NULL, port_name);
    printf("server available at %s\n", port_name);

    // server tells the client about the port_name
    MPI_Send(port_name, MPI_MAX_PORT_NAME, MPI_CHAR, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Comm client;
    MPI_Status status;
    while (1) {
        MPI_Comm_accept(port_name, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF, &client);
        int again = 1;
        while (again) {
            MPI_Recv(buf, MAX_DATA, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, MPI_ANY_TAG, client, &status);
            printf("server received sth!\n");   
            switch (status.MPI_TAG) {
            case 0: 
                MPI_Comm_free(&client);
                MPI_Close_port(port_name);
                MPI_Finalize();
                return 0;
            case 1:
                MPI_Comm_disconnect(&client);
                again = 0;
                break;
            case 2: /* do something */
                printf("case 2\n");
                break;
            default:
                /* Unexpected message type */
                MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);
            }
        }
    }
  } else{
    MPI_Status status;
    // client receives the port information from server
    MPI_Recv(port_name, MPI_MAX_PORT_NAME, MPI_CHAR, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

    MPI_Comm server;
    double buf[MAX_DATA];

    MPI_Comm_connect(port_name, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF, &server);
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        int tag = 2; /* Action to perform */
        MPI_Send(buf, MAX_DATA, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, tag, server);
        printf("client send somthing!\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
    MPI_Send(buf, 0, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 1, server);
    MPI_Comm_disconnect(&server);
  }

  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: Why should it happen out side of the MPI_Comm_World in this case ? And could you tell me when we use MPI_COMM_SELF instead.

Comment: MPI_COMM_SELF is a single process communicator. My understanding is that because the client/server is point-to-point communication (you could have multiple clients but only between two processed at the same time), so we use this communicator. In all the examples that I found out there (including your link), they used this communicator for the client/server case without explanation. I need to double check the standard.

Comment: The code works, but I think in line "MPI_Recv(buf, MAX_DATA, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, client, &status);" of rank 0 (Server), it  must be changed from 0 to 1 in 4th parameter. Because the server receives message from rank 1 (Client).

Comment: How do I have a simple chat between physic Windows machine and virtual Windows machine running from this code? In this case do we have to use socket in windows or does MPI do all the socket's mission (MPI_recv & MPI_send) ? In conclusion, the question is "how do we do socket programming in MPI ?"

Comment: MPI is not designed for that purpose. MPI is basically the communication layer for a high performance application which is running parallel code, i.e., a cluster of nodes connected to each other and they run a tightly coupled application. Note that a chat system requires that two instances (client and server) exist *independently* of each other. Over here everything is in *one* application and if you kill the client, the server dies and vice versa. You can do socket programming to create a chat system (without any need of MPI).

Comment: Also look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mpi/9416/process-creation-and-management/29185/establishing-connection-between-two-independent-applications#t=201704071413180428244) oncommunication between two independent applications that was provided by Shibli above.

Comment: I got this error : "Fatal error in MPI_Publish_name: Invalid service name (see MPI_Publish_name), error stack:
MPI_Publish_name(service="master", MPI_INFO_NULL, port="ncalrpc:DESKTOP-EKN1RD3[LRPC-0f086273c45da4800b] ncacn_ip_tcp:DESKTOP-EKN1RD3[3405] 1") failed"

Comment: I suggest to post that as a new question, so people that wrote it could comment on it and help you out.